# How to convert float value to another float value with some specified precession using python?

Tags: python

How to convert float value to another float value with some specified precision using python?

```
>>> a = 0.1
```

but actually value of a is

```
0.10000000000000001
```

But I need to convert a to 0.1 in float type.

Comment: `0.1` in `float` type is not possible; read this: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: but it dosen't  happen with `0.1`

Comment: @Hackaholic `>>> 0.1`
`0.10000000000000001`
Happens for me.

Comment: `'{:.30f}'.format(0.1)` returns `0.100000000000000005551115123126`

Comment: @DarthKotik >>> 0.1
0.1
. which version of python you are using???

Comment: @DarthKotik its the case with `0.1+0.2`

Comment: @Hackaholic It was 2.6.6. On 2.7.6 nothing like this happens.

Comment: @DarthKotik, it's still not possible to represent _exactly_ `0.1` as a float. Python's `repr` has just got smarter about how it shows the approximate value

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to have `0.1` *exactly* when using the `float` type, due to how numbers are stored internally.  [This offsite resources](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/) will hopefully explain the internals more easily.

Note that when you use the Python console it *may look like you have 0.1 exactly* but this is not true, as the code below shows

```
In [35]: a = 0.1

In [36]: print(a)
0.1 # Looks fine! But wait, let's print with 30 decimal places...

In [37]: print('{:.30f}'.format(a))
0.100000000000000005551115123126 # Uh oh.
```

This occurs because when printing in the console, only a certain number of decimal places are printed, and for 0.1 this number is such that where it starts to deviate from 0 is outside the range.

Python does have a [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/decimal.html) package which can provide support for decimal numbers, as below

```
import decimal

a = decimal.Decimal('0.1')

print(a)
# 0.1

print('{:.30f}'.format(a))
# 0.100000000000000000000000000000
```

Note that I've constructed the `Decimal` object using the string `'0.1'` as opposed to the float `0.1`. This is because if I had used the float then the `Decimal` object *would have contained the same "errors" that the float has.*

Comment: For me print is not an issue.









































































for example





142*0.1

the actual value is 

14.200000000000001

but i need to truncate and save it as 14.20000000

Comment: @Madhu I was using the printing as an example for others in the future as well as you. When it boils down to it though, **this is a limitation of the `float` type and there's nothing you can really do about it other than using a different type.**

Answer (score 0):

How about the round function: [Round](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round)

Comment: >>> round(0.10000000000000001,2)
The evalauated value is
0.10000000000000001

I am using python 2.5.1

Comment: @MadhuBilly It works on 2.7

Answer (score 0):

You can use `formate` function with float and `round` function also

```
>>> a = float(format(0.10000000000000001, '.1f'))
>>> a
0.1
>>> round(0.10000000000000001,2)
0.1
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all. You are simply hiding the issue by only printing to 1 decimal place. The number is still 0.10000...0001 etc.

Comment: @Ffisegydd correct me if i'm wrong but where is no float point value `0.1`.

Comment: @Darth exactly. It cannot be represented using the `float` type. If you do `print(0.1)` in the Python console then it will return `0.1` *only because Python doesn't print all the decimal places.* The number is still `0.100000000000000005551115123126...` in reality.

Comment: @Ffisegydd So issue is representing of numbers in computer memory and we can't do anything but hide to it and it's ok.

Comment: @Darth or in Python you can use `decimal` as I've explained in my answer.

Comment: don't think about printing in a console


for Example 142*0.1 the actual python calculated value is 14.200000000000001

but actually i need to truncate it to   14.20000000

and i need to comapare this float value with other float value

Comment: @MadhuBilly if you need to compare values then it works `>>> float(format(142*0.1, '.2f')) ==14.20000000`
True.